# Count like and unlike php

Tags: javascript, php, html

I written a simple script where users can post without sign up or log in, something like conffesion website, people can post and get like and unlike on their posts. I want to count like then sort by most popular and most newest and show it on a main page, and I tried literally everything but nothing seems to work, heres my code:

comment-like-unlike.php

```
    ?php
require_once ("db.php");

$memberId = 1;
$commentId = $_POST['comment_id'];
$likeOrUnlike = 0;
if($_POST['like_unlike'] == 1)
{
$likeOrUnlike = $_POST['like_unlike'];
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_like_unlike WHERE comment_id=" . $commentId . " and member_id=" . $memberId;
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

if (! empty($row)) 
{
    $query = "UPDATE tbl_like_unlike SET like_unlike = " . $likeOrUnlike . " WHERE  comment_id=" . $commentId . " and member_id=" . $memberId;
} else
{
    $query = "INSERT INTO tbl_like_unlike(member_id,comment_id,like_unlike) VALUES ('" . $memberId . "','" . $commentId . "','" . $likeOrUnlike . "')";
}
mysqli_query($conn, $query);

$totalLikes = "No ";
$likeQuery = "SELECT sum(like_unlike) AS likesCount FROM tbl_like_unlike WHERE comment_id=".$commentId;
$resultLikeQuery = mysqli_query($conn,$likeQuery);
$fetchLikes = mysqli_fetch_array($resultLikeQuery,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
if(isset($fetchLikes['likesCount'])) {
    $totalLikes = $fetchLikes['likesCount'];
}

echo $totalLikes;
?>
```

comment-add.php

```
    <?php
require_once ("db.php");
$commentId = isset($_POST['comment_id']) ? $_POST['comment_id'] : "";
$comment = isset($_POST['comment']) ? $_POST['comment'] : "";
$commentSenderName = isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : "";
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

$sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_comment(parent_comment_id,comment,comment_sender_name,date) VALUES ('" . $commentId . "','" . $comment . "','" . $commentSenderName . "','" . $date . "')";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (! $result) {
    $result = mysqli_error($conn);
}
echo $result;
?>
```

get-like-unlike.php

```
   <?php
require_once ("db.php");

$commentId = $_POST['comment_id'];
$totalLikes = "No ";
$likeQuery = "SELECT sum(like_unlike) AS likesCount FROM tbl_like_unlike WHERE comment_id=".$commentId;
$resultLikeQuery = mysqli_query($conn,$likeQuery);
$fetchLikes = mysqli_fetch_array($resultLikeQuery,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
if(isset($fetchLikes['likesCount'])) {
    $totalLikes = $fetchLikes['likesCount'];
}

echo $totalLikes;
?>
```

And my index.php code for posts and likes:

```
 <div class="comment-form-container">
            <form id="frm-comment">
                <div class="input-row">
                    <input type="hidden" name="comment_id" id="commentId"
                           placeholder="Name" /> <input class="input-field"
                           type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name" />
                </div>
                <div class="input-row">
                    <textarea class="input-field" type="text" name="comment"
                              id="comment" placeholder="Add a Comment">  </textarea>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <font color="white"><input type="button" class="btn-submit" id="submitButton"
                                               value="Publish" /></font>
                </div>

            </form>
        </div>
        <div id="output"></div>
        <script>
            var totalLikes = 0;
            var totalUnlikes = 0;

            function postReply(commentId) {
                $('#commentId').val(commentId);
                $("#name").focus();
            }

            $("#submitButton").click(function () {
                $("#comment-message").css('display', 'none');
                var str = $("#frm-comment").serialize();

                $.ajax({
                    url: "comment-add.php",
                    data: str,
                    type: 'post',
                    success: function (response)
                    {
                        var result = eval('(' + response + ')');
                        if (response)
                        {
                            $("#comment-message").css('display', 'inline-block');
                            $("#name").val("");
                            $("#comment").val("");
                            $("#commentId").val("");
                            listComment();
                        } else
                        {
                            alert("Failed to add comments !");
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                });
            });

            $(document).ready(function () {
                listComment();
            });

            function listComment() {
                $.post("comment-list.php",
                        function (data) {
                            var data = JSON.parse(data);

                            var comments = "";
                            var replies = "";
                            var item = "";
                            var parent = -1;
                            var results = new Array();

                            var list = $("<ul class='outer-comment'>");
                            var item = $("<li>").html(comments);

                            for (var i = 0; (i < data.length); i++)
                            {
                                var commentId = data[i]['comment_id'];
                                parent = data[i]['parent_comment_id'];

                                var obj = getLikesUnlikes(commentId);

                                if (parent == "0")
                                {
                                    if(data[i]['like_unlike'] >= 1) 
                                    {
                                        like_icon = "<img src='like.png'  id='unlike_" + data[i]['comment_id'] + "' class='like-unlike'  onClick='likeOrDislike(" + data[i]['comment_id'] + ",-1)' />";
                                        like_icon += "<img style='display:none;' src='unlike.png' id='like_" + data[i]['comment_id'] + "' class='like-unlike' onClick='likeOrDislike(" + data[i]['comment_id'] + ",1)' />";
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                           like_icon = "<img style='display:none;' src='like.png'  id='unlike_" + data[i]['comment_id'] + "' class='like-unlike'  onClick='likeOrDislike(" + data[i]['comment_id'] + ",-1)' />";
                                        like_icon += "<img src='unlike.png' id='like_" + data[i]['comment_id'] + "' class='like-unlike' onClick='likeOrDislike(" + data[i]['comment_id'] + ",1)' />";

                                    }

                                    comments = "\
                                        <div class='comment-row'>\
                                            <div class='comment-info'>\
                                                <span class='commet-row-label'>from</span>\
                                                <span class='posted-by'>" + data[i]['comment_sender_name'] + "</span>\
                                                <span class='commet-row-label'>at</span> \
                                                <span class='posted-at'>" + data[i]['date'] + "</span>\
                                            </div>\
                                            <div class='comment-text'>" + data[i]['comment'] + "</div>\
                                            <div>\
                                                <a class='btn-reply' onClick='postReply(" + commentId + ")'>Reply</a>\
                                            </div>\
                                            <div class='post-action'>\ " + like_icon + "&nbsp;\
                                                <span id='likes_" + commentId + "'> " + totalLikes + " likes </span>\
                                            </div>\
                                        </div>";

                                    var item = $("<li>").html(comments);
                                    list.append(item);
                                    var reply_list = $('<ul>');
                                    item.append(reply_list);
                                    listReplies(commentId, data, reply_list);
                                }
                            }
                            $("#output").html(list);
                        });
            }

            function listReplies(commentId, data, list) {

                for (var i = 0; (i < data.length); i++)
                {

                    var obj = getLikesUnlikes(data[i].comment_id);
                    if (commentId == data[i].parent_comment_id)
                    {
                        if(data[i]['like_unlike'] >= 1) 
                        {
                            like_icon = "<img src='like.png'  id='unlike_" + data[i]['comment_id'] + "' class='like-unlike'  onClick='likeOrDislike(" + data[i]['comment_id'] + ",-1)' />";
                            like_icon += "<img style='display:none;' src='unlike.png' id='like_" + data[i]['comment_id'] + "' class='like-unlike' onClick='likeOrDislike(" + data[i]['comment_id'] + ",1)' />";

                        }
                        else
                        {
                         like_icon = "<img style='display:none;' src='like.png'  id='unlike_" + data[i]['comment_id'] + "' class='like-unlike'  onClick='likeOrDislike(" + data[i]['comment_id'] + ",-1)' />";
                         like_icon += "<img src='unlike.png' id='like_" + data[i]['comment_id'] + "' class='like-unlike' onClick='likeOrDislike(" + data[i]['comment_id'] + ",1)' />";

                        }
                        var comments = "\
                                        <div class='comment-row'>\
                                            <div class='comment-info'>\
                                                <span class='commet-row-label'>from</span>\
                                                <span class='posted-by'>" + data[i]['comment_sender_name'] + "</span>\
                                                <span class='commet-row-label'>at</span> \
                                                <span class='posted-at'>" + data[i]['date'] + "</span>\
                                            </div>\
                                            <div class='comment-text'>" + data[i]['comment'] + "</div>\
                                            <div>\
                                                <a class='btn-reply' onClick='postReply(" + data[i]['comment_id'] + ")'>Reply</a>\
                                            </div>\
                                            <div class='post-action'> " + like_icon + "&nbsp;\
                                                <span id='likes_" + data[i]['comment_id'] + "'> " + totalLikes + " likes </span>\
                                            </div>\
                                        </div>";

                        var item = $("<li>").html(comments);
                        var reply_list = $('<ul>');
                        list.append(item);
                        item.append(reply_list);
                        listReplies(data[i].comment_id, data, reply_list);
                    }
                }
            }

            function getLikesUnlikes(commentId)
            {

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    async: false,
                    url: 'get-like-unlike.php',
                    data: {comment_id: commentId},
                    success: function (data)
                    {
                        totalLikes = data;
                    }

                });

            }


           function likeOrDislike(comment_id,like_unlike)
            {


                $.ajax({
                    url: 'comment-like-unlike.php',
                    async: false,
                    type: 'post',
                    data: {comment_id:comment_id,like_unlike:like_unlike},
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (data) {

                        $("#likes_"+comment_id).text(data + " likes");

                        if (like_unlike == 1) { 
                            $("#like_" + comment_id).css("display", "none");
                            $("#unlike_" + comment_id).show();
                        }

                        if (like_unlike == -1) {
                            $("#unlike_" + comment_id).css("display", "none");
                            $("#like_" + comment_id).show();
                        }

                    },
                    error: function (data) {
                        alert("error : " + JSON.stringify(data));
                    }
                });
            }



        </script>
```

comment-list.php

```
<?php
require_once ("db.php");
$memberId = 1;
$sql = "SELECT tbl_comment.*,tbl_like_unlike.like_unlike FROM tbl_comment LEFT JOIN tbl_like_unlike ON tbl_comment.comment_id = tbl_like_unlike.comment_id AND member_id = " . $memberId . " ORDER BY parent_comment_id asc, comment_id asc";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$record_set = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    array_push($record_set, $row);
}
mysqli_free_result($result);

mysqli_close($conn);
echo json_encode($record_set);
?>
```

Im really looking forward for some help, ive been working on this script for a while and this is the last thing I need before launching, thanks in advice!
Here's a picture of a website, just to see how its working

[image]

[image]

Comment: So...what seems to be the problem? I must say, handling likes and unlikes can end up being problematic. Check out this YouTube video for a good explanation: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RY_2gElt3SA

Comment: Likes and unlikes are working great but I dont know how to sort them by most liked

Comment: Where is your comment-list.php code? That seems like it would be the code we need to look at for sorting your comments.

Comment: I just added it, sorry for missing it

Comment: Is `tbl_like_unlike.like_unlike` column just an INT column keeping track of total number of likes or is there another row in `tbl_like_unlike` for each user that likes a comment?

Comment: Its int keeping track just of total number of likes, I posted the picture of datebase, check it if it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write your query in comment-list.php like this

```
$sql = "SELECT tbl_comment.*,tbl_like_unlike.like_unlike FROM tbl_comment LEFT JOIN tbl_like_unlike ON tbl_comment.comment_id = tbl_like_unlike.comment_id AND member_id = " . $memberId . " ORDER BY tbl_like_unlike.like_unlike DESC, tbl_comment.date DESC";
```

This will automatically sort your data to have comment with most likes on top and then sort by the newest date. So if a comment has the same amount of likes of another comment, the newest will show up on top.

**COMMENT RESPONSE**

You can do it in javascript like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if(i == 0) {
        //put comment at top of page
    } else {
      // Put comment in normal place
    }
}
```

Comment: Its working! How can I now show most liked post in a one section of website(just one top liked post)? I want most liked post to be displayed in a most liked section I already created, is something like that possible?

btw thanks a lot, will flag as asnwer

Comment: You can do it either server side or client side. You can just take the first item in your results in javascript and display it at the top of the page since you know it will be the most liked and most recent comment, or you can sort it on the server and send the first row by itself to the client. I'll edit my answer with an example.

Comment: Can you help me with it? im never worked with like and unlike and its pushing my nerves, do you need some code?

Comment: It will be similar to how you're listing out the comments in JavaScript already.