# Display most liked post on a page php

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I written a script where users can post without signing up or logging in and recieve likes. Sumbitted posts are being displayed on a page and post with most likes is first, which is great, but I created a Most Liked section where I would like to display post with most likes.

comment-like-unlike.php

```
  ?php
require_once ("db.php");

$memberId = 1;
$commentId = $_POST['comment_id'];
$likeOrUnlike = 0;
if($_POST['like_unlike'] == 1)
{
$likeOrUnlike = $_POST['like_unlike'];
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_like_unlike WHERE comment_id=" . $commentId . " and member_id=" . $memberId;
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

if (! empty($row)) 
{
    $query = "UPDATE tbl_like_unlike SET like_unlike = " . $likeOrUnlike . " WHERE  comment_id=" . $commentId . " and member_id=" . $memberId;
} else
{
    $query = "INSERT INTO tbl_like_unlike(member_id,comment_id,like_unlike) VALUES ('" . $memberId . "','" . $commentId . "','" . $likeOrUnlike . "')";
}
mysqli_query($conn, $query);

$totalLikes = "No ";
$likeQuery = "SELECT sum(like_unlike) AS likesCount FROM tbl_like_unlike WHERE comment_id=".$commentId;
$resultLikeQuery = mysqli_query($conn,$likeQuery);
$fetchLikes = mysqli_fetch_array($resultLikeQuery,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
if(isset($fetchLikes['likesCount'])) {
    $totalLikes = $fetchLikes['likesCount'];
}

echo $totalLikes;
?>
```

comment-add.php

```
    <?php
require_once ("db.php");
$commentId = isset($_POST['comment_id']) ? $_POST['comment_id'] : "";
$comment = isset($_POST['comment']) ? $_POST['comment'] : "";
$commentSenderName = isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : "";
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

$sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_comment(parent_comment_id,comment,comment_sender_name,date) VALUES ('" . $commentId . "','" . $comment . "','" . $commentSenderName . "','" . $date . "')";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (! $result) {
    $result = mysqli_error($conn);
}
echo $result;
?>
```

get-like-unlike.php

```
   <?php
require_once ("db.php");

$commentId = $_POST['comment_id'];
$totalLikes = "No ";
$likeQuery = "SELECT sum(like_unlike) AS likesCount FROM tbl_like_unlike WHERE comment_id=".$commentId;
$resultLikeQuery = mysqli_query($conn,$likeQuery);
$fetchLikes = mysqli_fetch_array($resultLikeQuery,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
if(isset($fetchLikes['likesCount'])) {
    $totalLikes = $fetchLikes['likesCount'];
}

echo $totalLikes;
?>
```

comment-list.php

```
 <?php
require_once ("db.php");
$memberId = 1;
$sql = "SELECT tbl_comment.*,tbl_like_unlike.like_unlike FROM tbl_comment LEFT JOIN tbl_like_unlike ON tbl_comment.comment_id = tbl_like_unlike.comment_id AND member_id = " . $memberId . " ORDER BY tbl_like_unlike.like_unlike DESC, tbl_like_unlike.date DESC";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$record_set = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    array_push($record_set, $row);
}
mysqli_free_result($result);

mysqli_close($conn);
echo json_encode($record_set);
?>
```

index.php:

```
<div class="comment-form-container">
            <form id="frm-comment">
                <div class="input-row">
                    <input type="hidden" name="comment_id" id="commentId"
                           placeholder="Name" /> <input class="input-field"
                           type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name" />
                </div>
                <div class="input-row">
                    <textarea class="input-field" type="text" name="comment"
                              id="comment" placeholder="Add a Comment">  </textarea>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <font color="white"><input type="button" class="btn-submit" id="submitButton"
                                               value="Publish" /></font>
                </div>

            </form>
        </div>
        <div id="output"></div>
        <script>
            var totalLikes = 0;
            var totalUnlikes = 0;

            function postReply(commentId) {
                $('#commentId').val(commentId);
                $("#name").focus();
            }

            $("#submitButton").click(function () {
                $("#comment-message").css('display', 'none');
                var str = $("#frm-comment").serialize();

                $.ajax({
                    url: "comment-add.php",
                    data: str,
                    type: 'post',
                    success: function (response)
                    {
                        var result = eval('(' + response + ')');
                        if (response)
                        {
                            $("#comment-message").css('display', 'inline-block');
                            $("#name").val("");
                            $("#comment").val("");
                            $("#commentId").val("");
                            listComment();
                        } else
                        {
                            alert("Failed to add comments !");
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                });
            });

            $(document).ready(function () {
                listComment();
            });

            function listComment() {
                $.post("comment-list.php",
                        function (data) {
                            var data = JSON.parse(data);

                            var comments = "";
                            var replies = "";
                            var item = "";
                            var parent = -1;
                            var results = new Array();

                            var list = $("<ul class='outer-comment'>");
                            var item = $("<li>").html(comments);

                            for (var i = 0; (i < data.length); i++)
                            {
                                var commentId = data[i]['comment_id'];
                                parent = data[i]['parent_comment_id'];

                                var obj = getLikesUnlikes(commentId);

                                if (parent == "0")
                                {
                                    if(data[i]['like_unlike'] >= 1) 
                                    {
                                        like_icon = "<img src='like.png'  id='unlike_" + data[i]['comment_id'] + "' class='like-unlike'  onClick='likeOrDislike(" + data[i]['comment_id'] + ",-1)' />";
                                        like_icon += "<img style='display:none;' src='unlike.png' id='like_" + data[i]['comment_id'] + "' class='like-unlike' onClick='likeOrDislike(" + data[i]['comment_id'] + ",1)' />";
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                           like_icon = "<img style='display:none;' src='like.png'  id='unlike_" + data[i]['comment_id'] + "' class='like-unlike'  onClick='likeOrDislike(" + data[i]['comment_id'] + ",-1)' />";
                                        like_icon += "<img src='unlike.png' id='like_" + data[i]['comment_id'] + "' class='like-unlike' onClick='likeOrDislike(" + data[i]['comment_id'] + ",1)' />";

                                    }

                                    comments = "\
                                        <div class='comment-row'>\
                                            <div class='comment-info'>\
                                                <span class='commet-row-label'>from</span>\
                                                <span class='posted-by'>" + data[i]['comment_sender_name'] + "</span>\
                                                <span class='commet-row-label'>at</span> \
                                                <span class='posted-at'>" + data[i]['date'] + "</span>\
                                            </div>\
                                            <div class='comment-text'>" + data[i]['comment'] + "</div>\
                                            <div>\
                                                <a class='btn-reply' onClick='postReply(" + commentId + ")'>Reply</a>\
                                            </div>\
                                            <div class='post-action'>\ " + like_icon + "&nbsp;\
                                                <span id='likes_" + commentId + "'> " + totalLikes + " likes </span>\
                                            </div>\
                                        </div>";

                                    var item = $("<li>").html(comments);
                                    list.append(item);
                                    var reply_list = $('<ul>');
                                    item.append(reply_list);
                                    listReplies(commentId, data, reply_list);
                                }
                            }
                            $("#output").html(list);
                        });
            }

            function listReplies(commentId, data, list) {

                for (var i = 0; (i < data.length); i++)
                {

                    var obj = getLikesUnlikes(data[i].comment_id);
                    if (commentId == data[i].parent_comment_id)
                    {
                        if(data[i]['like_unlike'] >= 1) 
                        {
                            like_icon = "<img src='like.png'  id='unlike_" + data[i]['comment_id'] + "' class='like-unlike'  onClick='likeOrDislike(" + data[i]['comment_id'] + ",-1)' />";
                            like_icon += "<img style='display:none;' src='unlike.png' id='like_" + data[i]['comment_id'] + "' class='like-unlike' onClick='likeOrDislike(" + data[i]['comment_id'] + ",1)' />";

                        }
                        else
                        {
                         like_icon = "<img style='display:none;' src='like.png'  id='unlike_" + data[i]['comment_id'] + "' class='like-unlike'  onClick='likeOrDislike(" + data[i]['comment_id'] + ",-1)' />";
                         like_icon += "<img src='unlike.png' id='like_" + data[i]['comment_id'] + "' class='like-unlike' onClick='likeOrDislike(" + data[i]['comment_id'] + ",1)' />";

                        }
                        var comments = "\
                                        <div class='comment-row'>\
                                            <div class='comment-info'>\
                                                <span class='commet-row-label'>from</span>\
                                                <span class='posted-by'>" + data[i]['comment_sender_name'] + "</span>\
                                                <span class='commet-row-label'>at</span> \
                                                <span class='posted-at'>" + data[i]['date'] + "</span>\
                                            </div>\
                                            <div class='comment-text'>" + data[i]['comment'] + "</div>\
                                            <div>\
                                                <a class='btn-reply' onClick='postReply(" + data[i]['comment_id'] + ")'>Reply</a>\
                                            </div>\
                                            <div class='post-action'> " + like_icon + "&nbsp;\
                                                <span id='likes_" + data[i]['comment_id'] + "'> " + totalLikes + " likes </span>\
                                            </div>\
                                        </div>";

                        var item = $("<li>").html(comments);
                        var reply_list = $('<ul>');
                        list.append(item);
                        item.append(reply_list);
                        listReplies(data[i].comment_id, data, reply_list);
                    }
                }
            }

            function getLikesUnlikes(commentId)
            {

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    async: false,
                    url: 'get-like-unlike.php',
                    data: {comment_id: commentId},
                    success: function (data)
                    {
                        totalLikes = data;
                    }

                });

            }


           function likeOrDislike(comment_id,like_unlike)
            {


                $.ajax({
                    url: 'comment-like-unlike.php',
                    async: false,
                    type: 'post',
                    data: {comment_id:comment_id,like_unlike:like_unlike},
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (data) {

                        $("#likes_"+comment_id).text(data + " likes");

                        if (like_unlike == 1) { 
                            $("#like_" + comment_id).css("display", "none");
                            $("#unlike_" + comment_id).show();
                        }

                        if (like_unlike == -1) {
                            $("#unlike_" + comment_id).css("display", "none");
                            $("#like_" + comment_id).show();
                        }

                    },
                    error: function (data) {
                        alert("error : " + JSON.stringify(data));
                    }
                });
            }
        </script>
```

I will post picture of a website just you guys have a clue what Im talking about:

[image]

This is where I want most liked post:

[image]

Comment: I'm curious; [didn't you ask this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53329035/1415724) already and gotten an answer? Or is this question different?

Comment: If you want to count, why are you using `SUM()` instead of `COUNT()`?

Comment: It is, I need to show most liked post in a desired section, as you can see in image, Ive got an answer how to sort them by most liked, but not how to display it in a page in a specific section

Comment: OK. Not my downvote btw. So, for my 2nd comment about SUM/COUNT. Using `COUNT()` would be easier I find. Note: I suggest you use a prepared statement since your code is open to injection.

Comment: Im kinda newbie in php, Im coding this website for few days and getting familiar with everything, thats probably why I used sum instead of count

Comment: Wanting to have the most liked, using `COUNT(col)` would probably be your best bet. I'm thinking out loud here of course, but if that isn't the problem here, then I can't see / understand what isn't working the way you want it to. What results are you getting now as opposed to the desired results?

Comment: I dont know how to use COUNT columns in this case, can you help me somehow? Maybe tutorial or help direct with a code

Comment: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-count/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Count like and unlike php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53329035/count-like-and-unlike-php)

Answer (score 0):

SELECT posts from your_table ORDER BY likes DESC

Comment: add LIMIT 1 to this query and you have a result